# Is it feasible to have a single sign on page for multiple datasources?

Tags: coldfusion, sql-server-2012

I am in the beginning stages of planning a web application using ColdFusion and SQL Server 2012.

In researching the pros and cons of using multiple databases (one per customer) vs one large database, for my purposes I have decided multiple databases would be the best approach.

With this in mind I am now wondering the best way to proceed regarding logging clients in.  I have two thoughts here:

1. I could use sub-domains with each one being for a specific client.  The sub-domain also being the datasource name.
2. I could have a single sign on page with the datasource for this client stored in a universal users table.

I like the idea of option 2 best however I am wondering how this may work in the real world.  Making each user unique would not be ideal (although I suppose I could make this off of an email address instead of a username).

I was thinking of maybe adding something along the lines of a "company code" that would need to be entered along with the username and password.

I feel like this may be asking too much of clients though.

With all of this said, would you advise going with option 1 or option 2?  Would also love to hear any thoughts or ideas that may differ.

Thanks!

Comment: If each customer is going to have their own database and coldfusion datasource, will they also not have their own application?  If they do, an application variable might be the way to go.

Comment: When I hear the term `large database` that could mean anything. Why do you think that the db is large enough to warrant having multiple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are expecting to have a large amount of data per client, it may be a good idea to split each client into their own database.

You can create a global database that contains client information, client datasource, settings, etc. for each client and then set the client database in the application.cfc.

This also makes it easier at the end if a client request their data or you would like to remove a client from the system.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Do you have any recommendations regarding a central login?

Comment: Managing users from a central source can become slow and tedious. To overcome this problem, create a splash page on the main page to look up the client's sub-domain either by Company Name/Company ID/etc. and have that redirect to the sub-domain where they can login.

Comment: Seems like the only issue with a central login is ensuring the usernames are unique.  Just means client XYZ can't have a user named SNARF if client ABC already has a user named SNARF.  I'd just have a rule to enforce unique usernames and let the users decide on their own if they want to be SNARF or SNARF@xyz.com or XYZ\SNARF or who know what else they come up with.

Comment: One problem you may encounter is that there are a lot of settings you would like to store/update for each user. With this in mind you will either have to modify/query the global table each time a change is made or you will have to Inner Join 2 tables from different databases (one with the username and password, one with the users extra settings).

Comment: Thank you for the additional input @ssteinbeck and Snipe656.  I've gone ahead and marked this as the answer.